# Mac Pro making clicking sound, my second HD disappeared

Tags: mac, hard-drive, hardware-failure

I have a Mac Pro, 2.8 GHz, quad-core Intel Xeon, 4 core machine. Two weeks ago, my second internal HD disappeared. That morning the computer was making clicking sounds when I booted up - it still does. Also, when the computer comes back up from sleep mode, it clicks. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds (Ha!) like a bad hard drive. Have it replaced.

You can try using something like [Diskwarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/) to repair the file-system, but it is *highly* unlikely that will work if the drive is making odd sounds.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking. Could I just remove the bad hard drive? I have the pre-installed HD, another 2TB HD, plus another 2TB external HD I use for backups. I am assuming this is overkill and I don't need to replace it.

Comment: You should just be able to remove the bad drive, yes.